# React - Wait for modal component to close and get the result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise, react-modal

I am struggling to understand how to use React modals (specifically React-Bootstrap) when asynchronous code is involved. I am learning about promises and React at the same time so I hope I am formulating the question correctly.

My goal is to launch an asynchronus function with parameters provided by a modal. This is what I am doing at the moment, it works, but I have the impression that I am not separating concerns.

When a button is clicked the async function `simulateImprovedBuilding` is launched.

```
async function simulateImprovedBuilding() {
  function selectOsMeasures(measures) {
    let selectedOsMeasures = measures;
    let scenario = "Improved";
    simulateBuilding(scenario, selectedOsMeasures).then((result) => {
      console.log("Finally!!!!");
      renderMonthlySimulation(result);
    });
  }

  const osMeasuresModalRoot = createRoot(document.getElementById("react_modal"));
  osMeasuresModalRoot.render(<OsMeasuresModal action={selectOsMeasures} />);
  console.log("Done");
}
```

The modal is rendered, I make the selection and the component execute `selectOsMeasures` to update the parameters, launch the long running async process and, when completed renders the results on a chart. This is the component

```
function osMeasuresModalRoot(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const handleClose = () => {
    setShow(false);
    let selectedOsMeasures = osMeasures.filter(x => selections[osMeasures.indexOf(x)]);
    console.log(selectedOsMeasures);
    props.action(selectedOsMeasures);
  };
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true); // Not used

  const [selections, setSelections] = useState([]);

  const [osMeasures, setOsMeaaures] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let url = `http://${osServer}/os_measures`;
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setOsMeaaures(result);
        setSelections(Array(result.length).fill(false));
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Select ECMs</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            {osMeasures.map((measure, index) => (
              <div key={`${measure}`} className="mb-3">
                <Form.Check
                  type={"checkbox"}
                  id={`${measure}`}
                  label={`${measure}`}
                  onChange={() => {
                    selections[index] = !selections[index];
                    console.log(selections);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Simulate
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

I think the `selectOsMeasures` function is doing too much. I think I should do something like:

```
simulateImprovedBuilding()
.then(result => renderMonthlySimulation(result));
```

But if I do this, the function exits immediately after the React `render` function and of course result is undefined.

First of all, is my concern valid? If so, how should I refactor my code?

Answer (score -1):

How about increasing the scope of the function and making the result global? It's a bit hacky but is more along the lines of what React should be doing rather than having multiple rendering functions. Then it will automatically switch between the Modal and the graph rendering function when it changes:

```
function SimulateImprovedBuilding() {

    let r_result = undefined;

    function OsMeasuresModal(props) {
        const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
        const handleClose = () => {
            setShow(false);
            let selectedOsMeasures = osMeasures.filter(x => selections[osMeasures.indexOf(x)]);
            console.log(selectedOsMeasures);
            props.action(selectedOsMeasures);
        };
        const handleShow = () => setShow(true); // Not used

        const [selections, setSelections] = useState([]);

        const [osMeasures, setOsMeaaures] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {

            let url = `http://${osServer}/os_measures`;
            fetch(url)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    setOsMeaaures(result);
                    setSelections(Array(result.length).fill(false));
                });
        }, []);

        return (
            <>
                <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Select ECMs</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Form>
                            {osMeasures.map((measure, index) => (
                                <div key={`${measure}`} className="mb-3">
                                    <Form.Check
                                        type={"checkbox"}
                                        id={`${measure}`}
                                        label={`${measure}`}
                                        onChange={() => {
                                            selections[index] = !selections[index];
                                            console.log(selections);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </Form>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <button  onClick={handleClose}>
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                        <button onClick={handleClose}>
                            Simulate
                        </button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </>
        );
    }

    function selectOsMeasures(measures) {
        let selectedOsMeasures = measures;
        let scenario = "Improved";
        simulateBuilding(scenario, selectedOsMeasures).then(r => {
            console.log("Finally!!!!");
            r_result = r;
        });
    }

    function Render() {
        return (
            <>
                {r_result===undefined? <OsMeasuresModal action={selectOsMeasures} /> : renderMonthlySimulation(r_result)}
            </>
        )
    }

    const osMeasuresModalRoot = createRoot(document.getElementById("react_modal"));
    osMeasuresModalRoot.render(<Render/>);
    console.log("Done");
}
```

Note: the `renderMonthlySimulation(r_result)` function will need to become a react component that returns what you want to render

Same can be done in multiple ways, you could use a ['Context'](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) across all the react functions, or use ['Routing'](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_router.asp) to switch between things you're rendering. It's much better to have a singular .render.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand how this solution would help. `simulateBuilding` needs to be called after the modal has been closed so that `selectedOsMeasures` has been set. Currently I do this via the `action` prop when I render the component. Maybe the question is not clear?

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't notice the function being passed, I will refactor the answer

Comment: Should be answering the question better now hopefully